# Is it wrong to have just one ubuntu docker container with everything I need?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create an application with Nginx, PHP and Mysql. But instead of using a container for each process, I want to run only ubuntu container with everything inside. Is it wrong to do this?

Comment: Is it "wrong"? No, not at all. Is it the most 'scalable enterprisey-orchestery'? Definitely not that either. Regardless, the question feels Too Broad for this site. What does web research reveal? Can this research be incorporated to focus the question?

Comment: @user2864740 Not to mention that it's an OS question and not a programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with creating one docker for all your services, given you configure them properly, basically in your case you have three services.

1. Ngnix
2. Your web-service written in PHP.
3. Mysql which stores the data.

Make sure, if you have external disk/volume attached to your docker containers which store your data as [by design docker containers are ephemeral](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/docker-how-to-use-it-in-a-practical-way-part-3/#containers-are-ephemeral) , so that you don't lose your data when these containers are killed and restart.

This is a very common use case and [using docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) you can easily achieve it.